# Is this how we measure our spiritual level?

Tags: spiritual-level, spirituality

[image: Spirituality Map]

Please see the image. Is this how we can measure our spirituality?

I think I am at 250. I am satisfied with it. What should one do if he is satisfied with his present level of spirituality?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto What is missing is the scriptural basis,These are modern day speculations using computer graphics.

Comment: @commonman Is there any way to measure by the way ? As per my understanding only Guru can tell right ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Any advanced soul can.Realised souls always can.Gurus are rarely advanced or realised

Comment: @commonman Let's talk here [chat on spiritual measurement](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53977/agama-and-tantra)

Comment: Your image depicts wrong after enlightenment nobody would go to darkness ..it should be white, reference uphanishad is saying Kath upanishad..

Comment: @Prasanna R I think it's just represented in Black that's all.. it's denoting Heaven phase..

Comment: This color does appear if you meditate.. that is indication of this image.. but one change black is last and instead of black its white that should be top..